# Which shortcut compiles user commands (different types of compyling) in texstudio

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, dvi, shortcut, keycommand

I want to run

- txs:///latex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///latex | txs:///latex | txs:///dvipdf | txs:///dvips | txs:///view
- txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex  | txs:///view
- txs:///dvi-ps-pdf-chain
- txs:///compile | txs:///view

depening on the file I am using.
As far as I know there is no Magic Comment for that.
But you can add a user command, how to compile in the [preferences](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a). I know there is a shortcut, but I don't know which shortcut.

Comment: the first one looks a bit odd, using dvips and dvipdf on the same file?

Comment: You can add `%!TeX program = ...` at the top of your master file, where the `...` are the compile options you listed above. Then this allows TXS to override your default compile options on a file-by-file basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) you can call the shortcut with <kbd>alt</kbd> & <kbd>shift</kbd> & <kbd>F%n</kbd>. For example for `user0:User Command 0` press <kbd>alt</kbd> & <kbd>shift</kbd> & <kbd>F1</kbd>.